# binary tree traversal code explaination needed

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have a question on how this binary tree traversal code works.

```
void BinaryTree_Functions::preorder(Binary_TreeNode* bt)
    {
        if (bt == NULL) { return; }
        cout <<  bt->data <<endl;
        preorder(bt->Left);
        preorder(bt->Right);
    }
```

preorder traversal

```
    void BinaryTree_Functions::inorder(Binary_TreeNode* bt)
    {
        if (bt == NULL) { return; }
        inorder(bt->Left);
        cout << bt->data << endl;
        inorder(bt->Right);
    }
```

inorder traversal

```
    void BinaryTree_Functions::postorder(Binary_TreeNode* bt)
    {
        if (bt == NULL) { return; }
        postorder(bt->Left);
        postorder(bt->Right);
        cout << bt->data << endl;
    }
```

postorder traversal

I know how these traversals work but I did not understand the code.

Comment: what do you not understand? Did you already use a debugger to step through the code line by line ?

Comment: Does it help to think about pre and post meaning before and after? And that it shows when to handle the current node?

Comment: Where is not much left to understand... `if (bt == NULL) { return; }` is in all three cases the  check whether the resp. function was called for a null pointer. (Better would have been `if (!bt)` or `if (bt == nullptr)` as this is C++.) The `cout << bt->data << endl;` represent the action applied to the current node. The left function calls are recursive calls on the left and right child node of the resp. tree node. The difference of pre-order, in-order, and post-order is specifically how the action on the node itself and the recursive calls for left and right child are ordered...

Comment: ...as this effects in which order the actions are applied to the individual nodes at all.

Comment: I don't understand how you can both know how they work *and* not understand the code, at the same time.

Comment: Do you understand what recursion is in general? If not this should be the starting point. Once you understand what recursion means it should be easy to understand this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dificult to explain when you don't say what specifically is confusing you. The issue seems to be recursion. To see more easily what happens you could use an example tree and see how the output differs. To see how the different orders traverse the three differently you can also look at this fake tree:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

struct fake_tree {
    unsigned size = 4;
    void preorder(const std::string& node){
        if (node.size() >= size) return;
        std::cout << node << "\n";
        preorder(node+"l");
        preorder(node+"r");
    }
    void postorder(const std::string& node){
        if (node.size() >= size) return;
        postorder(node+"l");    
        postorder(node+"r");
        std::cout << node << "\n";
    }
    void inorder(const std::string& node){
        if (node.size() >= size) return;
        inorder(node+"l");
        std::cout << node << "\n";
        inorder(node+"r");
    }
};

int main()
{
    fake_tree ft;
    ft.preorder("0");
    std::cout << "\n";
    ft.postorder("0");
    std::cout << "\n";
    ft.inorder("0");
}
```

output is:

```
0
0l
0ll
0lr
0r
0rl
0rr

0ll
0lr
0l
0rl
0rr
0r
0

0ll
0l
0lr
0
0rl
0r
0rr
```

The output tells you directly where in the call stack the output is produced. For example the last `0rr` is produced by `inorder("0")` calling `inorder("0r")` which in turn calls `inorder("0rr")`. Because `inorder("0")` first calls `inorder("0l")` then prints `"0"` and then calls `inorder("0r")`, thats the order you see in the output.

Similarly `inorder("0r")` first calls `inorder("0rl")` then prints `"0r"` then calls `inorder("0rr")`.

If you now draw the tree on paper you can track how the different traversals go through the tree in different ways.